# WebAPI async Task<IHttpActionResult> passing model

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api2

This is my controller

```
public class TutorController : ApiController
{

    [Route("CreateTutor")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateTutor(TutorModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }            

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

and I am using Fiddler to connect to it

POST http://localhost:12110/api/Tutor/CreateTutor

I have set raw and application/application

In Body I have

```
{
  "Name": "Test"
}
```

But I get this error
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:12110/api/Tutor/CreateTutor'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Tutor' that matches the request."
}

**Any idea what I am doing wrong?**

Comment: What does your Startup.cs file look like? you may not be using default route of "api/controller/action". You could also try placing [HttpPost] attribute on your controller method as well.

Comment: When you apply the `Route` attribute you are overriding the default route in the `WebApiConfig` file. Try accessing your controller with the following...it will probably work, thought it's probably not what you want:  http://localhost:12110/CreateTutor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every method in an API controller must have an attribute to determine it

You are missing the action attribute in your method such as the eg. below

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TutorController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("CreateTutor")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateTutor(TutorModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }            

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Read more in the MS docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#http-methods

Comment: Thanks turns out I was missing [RoutePrefix("api/Tutor")] above the class, still works without [HttpPost] attribute

Comment: This isn't true. See [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api).